# How can I remove a underline of Text on Android Wear Notification?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

[image]

Hello? I am developing a Android Wear Application.

Recently, I am testing my app on Galaxy Watch 4.

And I noticed that underline is added automatically to some texts which have series of number.

Here is a step to reproduce my problem.

Create a notification which have a content "2023. 12. 11" .

Notify the notification on Galaxy watch 4

If Galaxy Watch 4 show up that notification like Picture2, then click Notification Body.

Notification detail screen show up like picture4. And unwanted underline is added to text like picture3, 4.

I have tried many things to remove unwanted underline. Here are the things I have tried.

- Creating a custom notification layout. And Setting android:autoLink="none".(https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification)
- Adding Zero Width Space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between every characters in notificaiton
- Changing notification style (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded)
- Setting a `Spannable` to notification content. Custom `ClickableSpan` which override `onClick` method and do nothing.

None of tries fix issue.

Is there a way to remove that underline?

+)

[image]